# Dynamically evaluating Javascript from .ashx page

Tags: javascript, dynamic, ashx

I have written a custom HTTP handler (`.ashx`) and call it from an `.aspx` page. I am sending the Javascript code from the `.ashx` - and the `.alert()` shows the code. However, the `.eval()` does not seem to do anything. What could be wrong?

I have verified that when I directly use the generated Javascript in a plain old HTML file, it works fine.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/SimpleApp/SimpleHandler.ashx",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
          eval(data);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: There is probably a javascript error being thrown.  Check your debug console.

Comment: IN addition to @Squeegy's point, it might help if you told us what you wanted it to do, and showed us the code being sent across.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it that way.
Try this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getScript({
        url: "http://localhost/SimpleApp/SimpleHandler.ashx",
        success: function() {
          // do something after ashx (js) had been executed.
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten to include the Google Maps API in the headers section. But it still does not solve the issue.

Comment: @EagerNoob if my answer was helpful, i would love to receive the +1 :D